# Voltage of capacitor

Tags: electricity

I'm totally confused why when I attach directly my capacitor to source voltage, the current towards the capacitor will stop at the time that voltage of capacitor reach my source voltage value ... any clue?

Sounds weird to me.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? The voltage to continue rising without limit?

Comment: Yup why not?! and why it would stop whenever the voltage equal to each other?!

Comment: The rate at which the capacitor charges depends on two things: The parasitic resistances of the voltage source and the capacitor, and the difference in voltage between the capacitor and the source. When that voltage difference goes to zero, the charging current goes to zero as well.

Comment: First, you must assume that there is some finite resistance between the ideal capacitor and the ideal voltage source, otherwise the circuit can not be solved analytically. So, what you need to understand first is Ohm's law and that, for a capacitor, \$I = C\times\frac{dV}{dt}\$

Comment: it sounds weird to me that you cannot put more than 1 cup of coffee into a coffee cup ..... why should it not continue to fill without a limit?

Comment: @Elliot Alderson, there is an analytic solution - current is an impulse.

Comment: @Chu So current and power both become infinite? While that might satisfy a mathematician it is of no practical value.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson, we consider ideal components all the time. Connecting a practical voltage source directly to a capacitor will result in an impulse-like current that charges the capacitor to the source voltage in a dangerously short time.

Comment: @Chu I am well aware that ideal components are in common use. But circuit analysis that predicts infinite current has **no practical value**...that's my point. And "impulse-like" is not at all the same as "impulse". If there is **any** resistance in the circuit, as of course there is with a **practical** source, then the **current** is finite and the **power** is finite. There is an enormous difference between infinite and "finite but large". Infinite current? No thanks.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson Infinity is NOT a number. If you connect an ideal voltage source to an ideal capacitor you get an impulse of current. What's the problem?

Comment: @Chu What is the magnitude of the impulse? What size wire do I need to carry an impulse? I **know** that infinity is not a number... **that's my point**. A circuit analysis that yields a current value that is not a number is of **no practical value**.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson Depends what you mean by 'magnitude'. The weight, of the impulse is the unit impulse multiplied by the value of the voltage at t=0. In any case, whether it's of practical value or not is moot. The fact is that if an ideal voltage source is applied to an ideal capacitor, the current is an impulse. And if the connections are implemented by an ideal conductor then it doesn't need a fuse. We're forever dealing with ideal scenarios and then stepping back from this to take account of practicalities. Also, the impulse response is the fundamental relationship for dynamic systems.

Comment: @Chu Yes, my point **exactly**! "and then stepping back from this to take account of practicalities" in order to get a result that has **practical value**. If \$i = dV/dt\$, \$dV\$ is finite and \$dt=0\$ what is the value of \$i\$? At best you say that the current is infinite, at worst you through up your hands and say it is undefined.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, your drifting away from your statement: *first, you must assume that there is some finite resistance between the ideal capacitor and the ideal voltage source, otherwise the circuit can not be solved analytically*, which is incorrect.

Comment: @Chu You are correct, that was not the best choice of words on my part. But I stand by my second, third, fourth, and fifth comments that such a result is of no practical value. I'm keeping in mind the **context** of the question...a newcomer wanting to understand what happens to the voltage in such a circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Simply speaking, current flows when there is a potential *difference*, meaning a *difference* in voltage between two nodes (points) across a resistive element like a wire or a resistor. When the voltage at one node is higher than the voltage at the other, current flows between them through the resistance. When you charge a capacitor with a DC supply, assuming the capacitor is fully discharged to begin with, the capacitor voltage is 0 and is charged through a resistive element from the battery, which has its own voltage. The resistive element can either be an actual resistor or just a wire connecting the battery to the capacitor. As the capacitor charges, its voltage increases and when the capacitor's voltage equals that of the battery, no current flows between them, so the capacitor stops charging.

There are many more levels and explanations for this that get far more in-depth, but this is probably one of the simplest ways of putting it. Further details include the *capacitance*, which is related to the amount of charge the capacitor can store, and why after a time of being connected to the source it can no longer accept more charges. Read [this link](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/capacitors/all) and [this link](https://howtomechatronics.com/how-it-works/electronics/what-is-capacitor-and-how-it-works/) for more information.

Comment: So it's by definition, nothing else and nothing more ! thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that, but yes - the capacitor does not generate voltage, so you cannot get a higher voltage out of it than what you put in

Comment: @Ryan It's not by definition, it's by physics.

Comment: I got you sir! ; but still confused at digital circuit if there's a capacitor which it's discharging (assuming that case) then we say the Vout=0 ; but we are actually approximate it to 0, because it's not instantly the capacitor get discharged ! so it takes a time to reach to zero and not instant the vout=0 , so we are just approximating it. I mean we are claiming while discharging the capacitor, then the vout=0; actually it's not zero because it takes a time for capacitor to be discharged ..so we approximate the vout to zero

Comment: @Ryan To be completely honest I have no clue what you are talking about. You do not approximate the voltage of a capacitor to be zero. Its discharge follows a very distinct, mathematical curve that is affected by the capacitance and resistance of the circuit. This curve is described by the formula **Vc = V0*e^[-t/(R*C)]** where Vc is the voltage across the capacitor at the given time t, V0 is the initial voltage across the capacitor, t is the time elapsed since the discharge began, R is the resistance of the circuit, and C is the capacitance of your capacitor.

Comment: There is no *approximating the capacitor voltage to 0*. If a substantial amount of time t has elapsed since discharging of the capacitor first began, the voltage can be *assumed* to be 0. Keep in mind, however, that the definition of "a substantial amount of time" will vary depending on the capacitance - higher capacitance requires more time to discharge.

Comment: Dont worry I got you sir!

Comment: But now I have read about transistor, and your definition on the current isn't correct .. because at the transistor for example can be a voltage difference between Drain and Source .. but there's no current! ..so your definition if there's difference voltage then there's current .. isn't correct exactly !

Comment: @Ryan is correct, your statements that "current flows when there is a potential difference" is obviously false as written. It's easy to cite examples where there is a potential difference but no current flow, and I think you really meant to say something different. I think you should reword these sentences to make them less confusing to newcomers.

Comment: Okay, that's a fair argument. I definitely over-simplified things there. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If it weren't the resistance of the wire you're using to connect the voltage source to your capacitor, then the voltage across the capacitor would be instantaneously the voltage of your source.

Because of the resistance, it will require some time for the capacitor to reach the source voltage (approximately 5RC, where R is the resistance of the wire, and C is the capacitance).

Also, there is no such thing as current through a capacitor (except for unwanted leakage). When the charge builds up on its plates, a *changing* electric field is produced between the plates. By Ampere's law, this produces a magnetic field, which makes it look it its current (since, as you know, current produces magnetic fields), but isn't. This "fake" current through the capacitor is called *displacement current*.

Comment: "the resistance of the wire you're using..." -- and also the resistance of the voltage source and the resistance of the capacitor, and the contact resistance at every joint between them.

Comment: And besides that, claiming that displacement current isn't current is misleading and only going to confuse someone new to electronics.

Comment: For someone new in electronics, the "resistance of the wires" is enough to point out the big idea of why it takes time for the capacitor to charge.

Comment: So you would rather have them believe that there is current going through the capacitor rather than relying on some fundamental ideas from electromagnetism?

Comment: Considering how rarely the distinction between conductive and displacement current is necessary to make, especially for a beginner, I would consider it a needless complication when talking to a beginner. I point out the ESR of the capacitor and voltage source because those _are_ important concepts for a beginner to understand, and likely more significant in this case than the resistance of the wire. Bringing up contact resistance was probably overly pedantic, though.

Comment: I don't find it needless. A capacitor uses an insulator between its plates, yet "current flows through it". I'm not sure if I agree that this is pedagogically sound. I agree that ESR is an important concept, but, again, the main point is there being some resistance which causes the delay; simply using the "wires" as the "some resistance", without adding further detail, establishes that main point.

Comment: @Hearth I think it is equally misleading for you to talk about "contact resistance" when explaining things to a beginner. Students begin with circuits made of ideal elements, where every resistance must be explicitly drawn. Throwing in these "hidden" resistances breaks the analytical techniques they are taught, so I think we must be very careful to distinguish ideal elements from real, practical elements and not just say "the voltage source" without being clear about whether it is ideal or real.

Comment: Hi guys ! because I'm new ..I can't post a new thread for my new question. lets assume I have like this coordinates 1------5-------8 so between points [1,5] is a drop of specific resistor lets assume it's V1 , and the drop between [5,8] is drop V2 .. my question is: that points "5" found twice between two pieces so we shouldn't include it in the consideration of the second piece for calculating V2? ! so in order to calculate the drop V2 between [5,8] we shouldn't include the points "5" itself ..right?

Comment: @Ryan No, this is the wrong way to ask a question. Take the tour of the site, you only need one point to ask a question.